# Отправка письма через mail.ru

Tags: java, mail.ru, smtp-server

В моем приложении пользователи регистрируются, и их данные отображаются на веб-сервере.
Я хочу добавить функцию восстановления пароля, в котором, при введении логина, письмо со случайно сгенерированным паролем отправляется с адреса службы поддержки (xxxxxxxx@mail.ru, пароль xxxxxxxx) на почту пользователя (любой домен).
Как я могу отправить письмо средствами java?

Comment: Это скорее вопрос к серверной стороне, а не к андроид разработчикам

Comment: В среде android нельзя отправить письмо?

Comment: А у вас служба поддержки будет на андроид устройстве?

Comment: Просто судя по проблеме кейс такой: клиент с устройства отправляет запрос на сервер о смене пароля. На сервере генерируют новый пароль и высылают на почту клиенту. Я не вижу место, где андроид должен отправлять почту. Я может что не так понял?

Comment: А каким образом пароль высылается на почту клиента? У меня приложение как-то должно содействовать с почтовым сервером.

Comment: У вас есть сервер? Вы с устройства сделаете запрос на сервер с отправкой логина.  На сервере найдете по логину нужную почту и на нее посылаете новый пароль. На сервере пишете уже работу с почтой.

Comment: Это насколько я понимаю, нужно писать через php, в котором я не разбираюсь. Мне нужно именно через java.

Comment: Ну если у вас на сервере java то, можно и на java писать. Все зависит от сервера. У вас на чем сервер?

Comment: У меня на denwer было, недавно учил как через андроид сдеать запрос на сервер и получить json данные. Потом на 000webhost.com загрузил свои php файлы и базу, данные отображаются там.

Comment: Значит вам нужно это на php писать. https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/48759/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно. Для этого нужно использовать небольшие библиотеки, которые можно найти [тут](http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-sdk-smtp-email-tutorial/)

Затем изменить `_host = "smtp.gmail.com"`на `_host = "smtp.mail.ru"` и должно работать. Не пробовал так именно с `mail.ru`, но с другими почтами получалось.

Comment: По ссылке jar файлов не нашлось, скачал с другого места, добавил.
Now that you have added the files to the lib folder, for each one: right click->Build Path->Add to Build Path
Это для eclipse. А как быть в Android Studio?

Comment: После нажатия "Add as library" показывается ошибка Configuration with name 'default' not found

Comment: @HaykAbelyan просто закинь эти три папки в папку libs, пересобери gradle и используй тот класс, который описан в ссылке

Comment: Странно, но не отправляется ни через mail.ru ни через gmail.
Везде System.err
javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.getLocalAddress(InternetAddress.java:517)
javax.mail.internet.UniqueValue.getUniqueMessageIDValue(UniqueValue.java:99)
javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateMessageID(MimeMessage.java:2054)
javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2076)
javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2042)
javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:117)
package.Mail.send(Mail.java:104)

Проблема в методе Transport.send(msg) в скопированном Mail классе.

Comment: Другое решение нашлось тут, оно работает с различными почтовыми серверами:
http://www.ssaurel.com/blog/how-to-send-an-email-with-javamail-api-in-android/